# Scala function signature: What does (p: (T, B) ⇒ Boolean) mean?

Tags: scala

During reading Scala documentation i confused with some functions signature:

```
def corresponds[B](that: GenSeq[B])(p: (T, B) ⇒ Boolean): Boolean
```

So, what does exactly this mean?

```
(p: (T, B) ⇒ Boolean)
```

Comment: function from (T,B) to Boolean

Comment: There's even a `Full Signature` for some methods which gives you the real, non-simplified signature, like for the [`map`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.GenSeq@map%5BB%5D%28f:A=%3EB%29:Traversable%5BB%5D) method.

Answer (score 5):

It means `p` is a function taking two arguments of type `T` and `B` and returning `Boolean`.

Answer (score 2):

In `(that: GenSeq[B])`, `that` is a parameter's name, and `GenSeq[B]` is its type.

In `(p: (T, B) ⇒ Boolean)`, `p` is a parameter's name, and `(T, B) ⇒ Boolean)` is its type.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things at play here, which is what may be confusing you. I'll break down this declaration below:

```
def corresponds
  [B] // Type parameter
  (that: GenSeq[B]) // FIRST parameter list
  (p: (T, B) ⇒ Boolean) // SECOND parameter list
  : Boolean // return type
```

So, the first thing that might be throwing you off is the fact that Scala accepts multiple parameter lists. Doing so has multiple benefits:

- You can use syntactic sugars, such as: `(1 to 10).foldLeft(0) { case (a, b) => a + b }`;
- The types of the previous parameter lists can guide inference on subsequent parameter lists -- this happens on the previous example as well;
- The last parameter list can be "implicit".

In the function below, the first two reasons are most likely the reasons for using two parameter lists. Let's say you have something like this:

```
correponds(Gen.alphaStr)(_ != _)
```

The type `B` will be inferred to be `String`, so the types in the function that follows will all be known. No, if it was only a single parameter list, like this:

```
corresponds(Gen.alphaStr, _ != _)
```

then the type `B` would NOT be inferred, because it also depends on the type of the function. For example, here:

```
corresponds(Gen.alphaStr, (a: T, b: Any) => a != b)
```

the type of `B` would be `Any` instead of `String`. Now, because it cannot infer the type in the first case, the compilation would fail. Splitting in two parameter lists force the compile to rely solely on the first argument for inference, which eliminates the ambiguity.

And, then, there's syntactic sugars, such as:

```
corresponds(Gen.alphaStr) {
  case (x, "positive") => x > 0
  case (x, "negative") => x < 0
  case _ => x == 0
}
```

Not much difference between that and this:

```
corresponds(Gen.alphaStr, {
  case (x, "positive") => x > 0
  case (x, "negative") => x < 0
  case _ => x == 0
})
```

but readability is made of little things like that.

Now the SECOND factor at play is the syntax for function types. `b: (T, B) => Boolean` means the parameter named `b` has type `(T, B) => Boolean`, which means a function taking two parameters, the first of type `T` and the second of type `B`, and returning a value of type `Boolean`.

See various examples above for functions being passed as parameter.